# Opening image with ImageMagick via c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, imagemagick

Creating a simple project for an open image with ImageMagick.
Using simple code:

```
#include "Magick++.h"
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;
using namespace Magick;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *c = "test.png";
    cout << c <<  endl;
    try {
        InitializeMagick(*argv);

        Magick::Image img;

        img.read(c);
        img.write("logo.png");
    }
    catch (Exception &error_)
    {
        cout << "Caught exception: " << error_.what() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But while opening any image(img.read(c)) I get an error:

```
Caught exception: MyProject.exe: unable to open image `≡█I': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695
```

Work with: ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q8, Windows 7 x64

Comment: Try defining `c` as `const char *c = "test.png";` or even `const string c("test.png");`

Comment: The result is same. I also try to use path instead of variable

Comment: Please provide your **complete** program with the `#includes` and `main()` in case the problems are elsewhere. Also, maybe try `img.read("test.png")` and also try reading a JPEG in case the problem is that you don't have `libpng` installed correctly.

Comment: I add full source code into question. I try to open different image format like png, jpeg, yuv, bmp. The result is same on all format

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code, so I have to suspect something went wrong with your installation and/or your compiler/linker settings. I can only suggest you try re-installing from scratch and checking that everything you are running matches in terms of version numbers, and 32-bit vs 64-bit etc. Sorry.